# Union tables with spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables one is `Users` and the other is `UserGroup` Having `ManyToMany` relationship , how can I union them into a single List with spring-data-JPA .

**  don't want to use native Queries

**UPDATE**:

The exact query that I need:

SELECT email FROM user

UNION

SELECT title FROM group

Comment: I didn't understand the question, do you want to join the tables into a JPA query(and you already have the entities), or do you want to know how to map them into an entity?

Comment: @vc73 not i don't want to join them i want the result of ' UNION' query of these tables

Comment: They are 2 completely different things. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @AlanHay think of it like result is gonna be used as list of users or group of users that can be choosed to receive email or sth like that

Comment: Make it as Native Query. It will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved my problem with creating a view in database itself and then map that to my java entity because it seems that hibernate doesn't support 'union' query

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? How did you accomplish this? What does the view look like?

Answer (score 7):

If you want union, I guess the structure of these 2 entities are similar.

You could create a super entity and make User and UserGroup extend this new entity. Add `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` on the new entity if you want to keep 2 separate tables.

Then, create a Spring Data JPA Repository for the parent entity.

```
/**
 * new abstract Superclass
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    //...
}

/**
 * Existing User entity
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="my_users")
public class LoginUser extends User {

    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

    //...
}

/**
 * Existing Group entity
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="my_groups")
public class Group extends User {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group")
    private Set<LoginUser> users;

    //...
}

/**
 * Super repository, providing UNION
 */
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {}
```

Calling `UserRepository.findAll` will make JPA do the `UNION` of the 2 tables, and can return a `List<User>`. You'll have both `LoginUser` and `Group` instances in this list:

```
// UNION query returning both LoginUser and Group instances
List<User> myUnion = userRepository.findAll();
```

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance for more details about JPA inheritance.

JPA/Hibernate don't support custom UNION queries, but inheritance provides out-of-the-box UNION between entities of the same hierarchy when using `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy.

You cant generate the query you want with JPA. It's not possible to UNION the different fields. But if you map email and title to the same field (which is a nonsense) and write the following JPQL, JPA will generate your query.

```
 SELECT u.yourField FROM User u;
```

Comment: actually tables don't need to have commens in union . I updated the question and added the query I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nativeQuery:

```
@Query("select u.email from user u union select g.title from group", nativeQuery = true)
public String findResult();
```

Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native