# Hibernate paging query returns no records with DB2/400 dialect

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, db2-400

I am using Vaadin Flow together with Spring-data-jpa and Hibernate with DB2/400 dialect. I am trying to use paging queries as my dataset could be very large. I have Hibernate logging on so that I can see the statements that Hibernate is executing. It works for the first page as the Hibernate query just asks for the first 50 records. However for the second page it asks for 100 records and filters out the first 50 but the query does not return any results. A slightly simplified version of the Hibernate generated query is:

```
select * from (
 select inner2_.*, rownumber() over(order by order of inner2_) as rownumber_ from ( 
  select * from flxalll1 flxalll1x0_ where upper(flxalll1x0_.aoukey) like upper('%te%') fetch first 100 rows only 
 ) as inner2_ 
) as inner1_ where rownumber_ > 50 order by rownumber_;
```

I have run this myself using the IBMi Run SQL Script tool and no results are returned. However, if I just do the inner two selects:

```
select inner2_.*, rownumber() over(order by order of inner2_) as rownumber_ from ( 
 select * from flxalll1 flxalll1x0_ where upper(flxalll1x0_.aoukey) like upper('%te%') fetch first 100 rows only 
) as inner2_ ;
```

I get the expects list of result, though of course all of them and not just the last 50. I have done some more experimentation and discovered that (unsurprisingly) this works:

```
select * from ( 
 select * from flxalll1
);
```

in that it lists all the records, but this:

```
select * from ( 
 select * from ( 
  select * from flxalll1
 )
);
```

produces no records.

Obviously there is no sense in that but I'm wondering if there is a problem with DB2/400 in that it won't do a select with two nested sub-selects, or something like that, and is that the reason why my original query does not return any records?

Solving the problem could be tricky but for now at least I am just trying to work out where the problem lies.

Comment: Just chatting to a (non-programmer) colleague and he mentioned something that made me think.

Comment: In my (real) example the table flxalll1 is (in IBMi terms) a logical (which combines a view and an index) where 10 other very similar tables are UNIONed together. If I try the triple nested select on other logicals then it works fine, returning records. So I think this is only not working because of the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my problem by not using the (IBMi) logical as mentioned in my comment above but by allowing spring data jpa to do the UNION. I created an abstract super class for my 10 tables and changed their Java class declarations to extend it.

I am indebted to this post and to the answer by Patrice Blanchardie:

[Union tables with spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829684/union-tables-with-spring-data-jpa)